# How can I dynamicly set height of two rows with changing content

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, height, rows

I'm trying to make sidebar with fixed position. It consists of:

- header with fixed height.
- div with dynamic content (list of ppl and their details).
- div with chat area (also dynamic).
- footer with input and send button, always positioned on the bottom.

After few hours I have this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Nippon/cVnDf/

```
var $window = $(window),
    $wrapper = $('.chat');

$window.resize(function(){
      $wrapper.css({
          height: $window.height() * 0.55 - 105 + "px"
      });
}).resize();
```

It's not working completly as I intented (kinda new to jquery). How can I set height of chat div to always fill the screen, resize on smaller resolution/window resize and react to expanding/collapsing name blocks and deleting/adding one (there won't always be 3 blocks)?

Comment: What do you want it to do that it isn't doing at the moment?

Comment: Well it didn't scale very well (on 1650x1080 and up) and removing/expanding user blocks was affecting chat area. Copy code from answer below to my fiddle and see the difference :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you were intending to do with `* 0.55`. If you want the chat to fill the remaining space, it's a matter of subtracting the heights of the other elements from the total window height, like so:

```
$window.height() - $(".topWrapper").outerHeight() - $(".sendArea").outerHeight()
```

I'm using `outerHeight()` to account for any margins and padding.

I also find it easier to create a separate function to apply the height, which can be applied on resize, on expanding the menu, etc.

--

Edit: You also need to make sure setHeight fires *after* the toggle animation finishes, so the height is accurate. Try this:

```
var $window = $(window),
$wrapper = $('.chat');

function setHeight() {
    th = $(".topWrapper").outerHeight();
    sa = $(".sendArea").outerHeight();
    $wrapper.css("height", $window.height() - th - sa - 20);
}

$window.resize(function(){
    setHeight();
}).resize();

$(".daneExpand").click( function() {
    $('.dane').not($(this).next()).slideUp(400);
    $(this).next().slideToggle(400, setHeight);
});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! That's brilliant and nails it! Earlier I was trying to pin-point/guess the right %height, but it was working fairly good only on small screens.

Comment: No problem! When you have enough reputation points, it'd be great if you could come back and vote my answer up. :)